# Getting weird result when adding array of numbers in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, integer

Following is my code in which is working fine for smaller array number, but if I am using large size number of array in the method it is giving weird answers -

Code -

```
function upArray(arr){
  var fail = false,
      count = '';
  arr.map(function(x){
    if(x>10 || x<0 || x== null || x== undefined)
      fail = true;
    else {
      count += x.toString();
      fail = false;
    }
  })
  if(arr.length < 1)
    fail = true;
  return fail ? null : (parseInt(count)+1).toString().split("").map(function(x){return parseInt(x);});
}
```

**Correct result** -

```
console.log(upArray([2,4,5])); //[2,4,6]
console.log(upArray([2,5,1])); //[2,5,2]
console.log(upArray([2,8,9])); //[2,9,0]
```

**BUT** - If I am giving a large array of numbers, its giving weird results -

like -

`console.log(upArray([9,2,2,3,3,7,2,0,3,6,8,5,4,7,7,5,8,0,8]));`

giving - `[9, 2, 2, 3, 3, 7, 2, 3, 6, 8, 5, 4, 7, 7, 5, 8, 0]`

Let me know what I am doing wrong over here and what is the fix ?

Answer (score 1):

Your `parseInt(count)+1` is exceeding the maximum safe integer in JavaScript, `Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER`, which gives the unexpected results.

A possible working implementation could be:

```
function upArray(arr){
  var result = [],
      remaining = 1;
  while (arr.length) {
    var x = arr.pop();
    if (x > 10 || x < 0 || x == null) { // x == null works for undefined as well
      return null;
    }
    if (remaining) {
      var _x = x + remaining;
      x = _x % 10;
      remaining = Math.floor(_x / 10);
    }
    result.unshift(x);
  }
  if (remaining) {
    result.unshift(remaining);
  }
  return result;
}
```

This works because it increments the integers one by one starting from the right untill there is no overflow (overflow is from 9 to 0).

Answer (score 0):

The input you are giving it is larger than the largest integer JavaScript supports, which is +/- 9007199254740991. It only supports 53-bit integers. See [What is JavaScript's highest integer value that a Number can go to without losing precision?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/307179/what-is-javascripts-highest-integer-value-that-a-number-can-go-to-without-losin).

Answer (score 0):

Like danmcardle noted your integer is too big.
Have a look at this SO question: [What is JavaScript's highest integer value that a Number can go to without losing precision?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/307179/what-is-javascripts-highest-integer-value-that-a-number-can-go-to-without-losin?lq=1)

Furthermore your code could be optimized a lot I think.

```
function upArray(nr){
  nr++;
  var nrString = nr.toString();
  return nrString.split('');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What you're doing is asking for trouble.

You are:

1. Mapping an array of integers into single-char strings and concatenating
2. Parsing the result into an integer
3. Adding 1 to the integer
4. Converting the result into a string and splitting back into a single-char array
5. Parsing each character back to an integer.

Your problem occurs when you attempt to do this with an array of integers that would concatenate into the integer `9223372036854775808`.  This is larger than `Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER`, so your call to `parseInt(count)` will not return what you expect it to. (`9223372036854776000` in this case).

Also, accepted best practice is to avoid `==` and `!=` completely.  Always use the strict quality operators `===` and `!==`.

Answer (score -1):

Two problems:

1. Your last value is larger than the [maximum integer value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/307179/what-is-javascripts-highest-integer-value-that-a-number-can-go-to-without-losin) supported by JavaScript
2. Even on smaller numbers, you'll throw away `0`s within the array, since `0 == null` and `0 == undefined`. You need to use `===` to check for value *and* type equality.

```
if (x > 10 || x < 0 || x === null || x === undefined)
```